# Retrieving the error elements in Pega 8.1 Tree Navigation Flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, pega

I am currently working on Pega. I am basically new in it. Pega version which I am working is 8.1.

Actually in the flow while submitting a form whenever there are validation errors in the required fields there an alert pops up. But as far as UI and UX the window needs to scroll with a subtle animation to the error fields, this I can do perfectly for any HTML page using jquery, but as I am new to Pega, I am facing a problem to get the error fields.

What I find, the error fields are appending on the relevant fields whenever there are validations, but catching those elements are going undefined.

I am sharing the simple code which I have written:

```
var validateScroll = function(){
  var getErrors = function(){
  this.parent = "";
 }

 getErrors.prototype.getErrorfn = function(node){
   this.parent = $(node);
   var errorLabels = this.parent.find('.dynamic-icon-error');
   console.log(errorLabels.attr('class'))
 }
 var a = new getErrors();
  var scrollfn = function(){
    var forms = $(document).find('form')[0];
    var _FORM = $(forms);

    _FORM.on('submit',a.getErrorfn(_FORM));

  }
  return{
    init:function(){
      scrollfn();
    }
  }
}();
$(document).ready(function(){
  validateScroll.init();
})
```

The result I am getting is "undefined", since those are appending and not  caught in the DOM.

Can anyone please suggest me any process? Is there any API to get the error fields in javascript. I have searched their Javascript API, but couldn't find any such API.

I have also asked this on PDN but got no reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `Validate` rules ?

Comment: No I am not validating rules, I am just trying to get the error DOMs

Comment: I am asking which rule of `Pega` is used to do the validation ? If you are using `Validate` rule then as I know if you use the UI properties properly in `validate` rule then Pega automatically points to the field on which error has occurred. If it is not happening automatically then ask you lead to raise a SR in MSP portal of Pega.